# Connect Gmail with Cypress

Tags: gmail, cypress

Can i have all the steps that connect cypress with Gmail?!
I tried to connect that but no success :(

I have fill the form, submit the form. Email comes in the email adress but now I need to access that and take a link and to click it to confirm the email.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

there is a quite a comfortable node module, that is not exactly Cypress specific but can be used within Cypress for the task in question with some tinkering. It has al the required examples though. Check it out, it's called [gmail-tester](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gmail-tester).

Comment: If someone else has this problem checkout this out. 
Read the documentation carefully, thanks Viktor